# JUnit and test files

Tags: java, junit

I have a large number (hundreds to thousands) of test files in an application I am developing.
What is the proper way to test my code against all those files as part of a `JUnit` test or test suite?

I could obviously write a single test method that loops through, all *N* files but I do not want a **single** fail/pass verdict on whether *all* test files were successfully handled.

Is there a way to get JUnit to report explicitly and separately on **each** test file instead?

Comment: Sounds like a data-driven test.

Comment: Assert.fail("the name of the file") ? Of course you may thing of something that is common for a set of file and groupe those in separate test methods

Comment: @DaveNewton yeap; that's exactly the terminology I was looking for. Data driven where the test cases are individual test files (or in some cases  directories that contain additional configuration and testing files organized under each directory)

Comment: @A4L wouldn't that approach require me to write N test methods (either by hand or by auto-generating the code)?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus not necessary, you could have only one loop and when a file fails to pass the test just report its name in the fail message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `ErrorCollector` for your verification. This will allow all files to be tested and give all files that fails (put file name as message in check).

[ErrorCollector](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html)

Comment: I am accepting this answer even though the ErrorCollector does not seem suited to generate a statistic in the form of e.g. "1353 files pass, 32 files failed"; it only reports failed cases (if I am not missing anything).

Comment: True. However, you could do that logging yourself at the end of the test since ErrorCollector will not stop execution. You might also be able to use `Parameterized`

Comment: By 'logging yourself' I guess you are referring to a console `printf` statement. That logging however would not appear on the HTML generated by the junit xml formatter would it?

Comment: That is correct. That is where you might look at `Parameterized`. The `getData` method could return the list of files to test.

Comment: I tried the `Parameterized` and it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great. Sorry I didn't mention it first.